# angular interceptor is not executed

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently trying to get my HTTP_INTERCEPTORS working using angular 14.
My target is to use the refresh_token stored at my local storage to obtain a new access_token. Currently, it seems that my interceptor is not triggering at all.
Is there maybe another place I also have to include the interceptor?

auth.service.ts:

```
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, public jwtHelper: JwtHelperService) {
  }

  getJwtToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
  }

  refreshToken() {
    return this.http
      .post<any>(environment.backend + '/api/v1/token/refresh', {
        refresh: localStorage.getItem('refresh_token')
      })
      .pipe(
        tap((tokens) => {
          localStorage.setItem('access_token', tokens.access);
        }
      ));
  }
```

token.interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpErrorResponse,
  HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { Observable, throwError, BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, filter, take, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private isRefreshing = false;
  private refreshTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(
    null
  );

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    //geeet token from local storage
    if (this.authService.getJwtToken()) {
      request = this.addToken(request, <any>this.authService.getJwtToken());
    }

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
          return this.handle401Error(request, next);
        } else {
          return throwError(error);
        }
      })
    );
  }

  private addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string) {
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });
  }

  private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (!this.isRefreshing) {
      this.isRefreshing = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

      return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
        switchMap((token: any) => {
          this.isRefreshing = false;
          this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token['result'].accessToken);
          return next.handle(this.addToken(request, token['result'].accessToken));
        })
      );
    } else {
      return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
        filter((token) => token != null),
        take(1),
        switchMap((jwt) => {
          return next.handle(this.addToken(request, jwt));
        })
      );
    }
  }
}


export const tokenInterceptor = {
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: TokenInterceptor,
  multi: true
};
```

And finally my app.module.ts

```
export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem("access_token");
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    FaqComponent,
    UserCounterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    AuthModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
        allowedDomains: ["example.com"],
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [Title, tokenInterceptor],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I originally found the implementation here:

https://medium.com/@an.sajinsatheesan/refresh-token-interceptor-angular-10-d876d01561be

Comment: Do you provide your AuthService in root?
your code should look like

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService ...

Comment: Basically, yes I do.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see your AuthService in 'app.module' It seems you have another module. So double-check other modules do not import 'HttpClientModule'
On the other hand, you should only import 'HttpClientModule' in 'app.module'.
According to angular docs:

> Because interceptors are optional dependencies of the HttpClient service, you must provide them in the same injector or a parent of the injector that provides HttpClient. Interceptors provided after DI creates the HttpClient are ignored.

Comment: I also came across this issue here on StackOverflow. Sadly, this is not the case. I only import it once and that's at app.module.ts